# Wireless data streaming with Rasbperry Pi 3

Tags: pi-3, python-3

What is the simplest way to stream sensor data obtained by a Raspberry Pi 3 to my laptop? I have my Pi reading data from a gyroscope and I'm wanting to plot the data on my laptop as it is received (preferably over wifi). I'm not asking for help with the plotting, just with creating the data stream.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this type of thing I usually recommend MQTT.  Here's a good broker/client that will work on both the Pi and your laptop: https://mosquitto.org/

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

This question is probably off-topic, as opinion based, and any protocol could be used.

However there is **standard** solution using `sockets`.

[PIgpio](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/index.html) provides a ready built solution for accessing GPIO.